# How do i get comma delimated (split) string value and pass it to a controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL table called Products and within the table i have field called `AvailableSizes` type of `NVARCHAR` that holds all the available sizes for a product. Then i separated the value of `AvailableSizes` Field as following in my view:

```
<p>
    <b>Available Sizes</b>
    @{
        var Availablesize = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
    }
    @foreach (var item in Availablesize)
    {
        <div class="circleBase type2">@item</div>
    }
</p>
```

As you can see in above code i placed those data values in side circles, now i want that if someone clicks one of those circles which holds the data inside it that value should be selected and then if the user clicks on AddToCart button it should be passed to my controller action which is below:

```
public RedirectToRouteResult AddToCart(Cart cart, int productId, string returnUrl)
{
    Product product = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productId);
    if (product != null)
    {
        cart.AddItem(product, 1);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { returnUrl });
 }
```

And here is the code behind for Add To Cart button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart", new { ProductID = item.ProductID}))
{
    @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" value="Add to cart" />
}
```

Just as far as I am new to MVC i need a clear solution to this, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you is using another hidden helper for selected size and populate that by click event of chosen `Availablesize` in Jquery. Then you could pass it to controller `AddToCart` action.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class when user select circle and then when user click on add cart button using jquery first fetch that selected circle value and pass data to controller in action method.

**Here is sample code to understand the logic**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.circleBase ').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('abc');
    })
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var result = $('.abc').val();
    //
    and call your controller
    });
});
```

class 'abc' is your class that highlighting selected items.